# beamer and tikz-uml package are not working together

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I use pretty cool `tikz-uml` in my LaTeX with class `report`. Its works very well!!!

Today, I’m start prepare presentation with `beamer`. I import all my `tikzpicture`s from `report` TeX without problems.

But, when I start import UML diagrams (class/sequence diagrams) I have error.

This happens on line `\usepackage{tikz-uml}` , in the beginning of my `beamer` file.

Here is error output:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
Overfull \hbox (8.46622pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 299--299
 []

 Overfull \hbox (89.75618pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
  [][]
  [11]
  Overfull \hbox (17.70491pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 325--325
   []
   (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd)

   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available
   (Font)              Font shape `T1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 325.


   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <10> not available
   (Font)              Font shape `T1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 325.


   Overfull \hbox (89.75618pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
    [][]
    [12]
    ! No room for a new \count .
    \ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                      \fi
                                                      l.349 \end{frame}
```

I have verson 0.98 of `tikz-uml.sty`, downloaded from site.

Here is beginning of my TeX file

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %russian support
%\usepackage[francais]{babel} %francais, ussian support
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %set standart fonts T1. It is Sexy!;Accent codés dans le font

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage {listings}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} % biblio items
\usepackage{url} % url


%TIKZ pictures packages
\usepackage{calc}   %chart diagrm
\usepackage{ifthen} %chart diagrm
\usepackage{tikz}   %chart diagrm
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}   % to draw flow diagramm
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata} %to draw fsm

\usepackage{subfig}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % set default alinéa; pour les paresses. Not use it!
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{float} %subfloat constructions for graphiques 



%listings
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}


\usepackage{ucs}            %russian support; dependency for lstset
\lstset{ %listing: add accents to 'caption'; default settings for each listings
extendedchars=\true,
inputencoding=utf8x
}
%\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
%\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
%\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}


%FOR DIAGRAMM CHARTSS
\newcommand{\slice}[4]{
  \pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
  \let\midangle\pgfmathresult

  % slice
  \draw[thick,fill=red!50] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

  % outer label
  \node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};

  % inner label
  \pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
  \let\temp\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
  \let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
  \node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3};
}

\usepackage{lmodern} %Make text more precise


\usepackage{subfloat}

%%UML, Stata machines
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfopts}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
...
```

Comment: Maybe if you can remove the irrelevant packages that does not contribute to the problem and make your problem smaller and complete, we can have a look. It is not possible to see why you have exhausted all the counters. I can't check it before I install almost a new TeX distribution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A few tips: writing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), and [how to mark inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load the `etex` package. That should give you access to etex's extended count registers so you have 32768 registers instead of 256.